# Sources of $\ce{CO_2}$ during Carboniferous period

Tags: paleoclimatology, carbon-cycle

It is believed that during the Carboniferous period, fungi and bacteria lacked the biochemical means to decompose lignin and release $\ce{CO_2}$ back to the atmosphere. So dying trees carbon became trapped in coal deposits. But whence came all carbon allowing these plants grow?

Comment: "it is known"? Is there any actual evidence?  I thought it was more speculation that a) appears logical; and b) is then used to help explain the high amount of preserved organic material (ie. coal).

Comment: Maybe change 'known' to 'believed' (besides, that's about as good as it gets in geology :), and offer a reference? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: thnks for help. I edited the question.

Comment: Stellar nucleosynthesis is surely the answer to the question as it stands. It might be better to ask how the carbon cycle worked before the advent of bacterial/fungal degradation of lignin? or to think about how long (probably not too long) it took for life to evolve a way to get the carbon out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terrestrial vegetation makes ca. 500 PgC (i. e. $500 \times 10^{15}$ grams of Carbon) which is rather small compared to the carbon stored in the ocean of ca. 37 000 PgC, see Fig. 6.1 in Ciais et al. 2013 <sup>1</sup>.
Even if we assume that the fossil fuels reserves are the remainders of the Carboniferous period, they only add up to no more than ca. 2 000 PgC.

The terrestrial biosphere only makes use of a very small portion of the total available carbon.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ciais, P., C. Sabine, G. Bala, L. Bopp, V. Brovkin, J. Canadell, A. Chhabra, R. DeFries, J. Galloway, M. Heimann, C. Jones, C. Le Quéré, R.B. Myneni, S. Piao and P. Thornton, 2013. [Carbon and Other Biogeochemical Cycles](http://www.ipcc.ch/pdf/assessment-report/ar5/wg1/WG1AR5_Chapter06_FINAL.pdf). In T. F. Stocker et al. (Eds): *Climate Change 2013: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of Working Group I to the Fifth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change*. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, United Kingdom and New York, NY, USA.</sub>

Comment: @plannapus: Well spotted, I changed that to "terrestrial"

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, if we assume that the earth's atmosphere (and water) came largely from comets, then it's simply about asking, what are comets made of - $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{NH3}$, other ices, dust.    $\ce{CO2}$ is abundant, it arrived pretty much the same way the water did.    The earth has trapped/absorbed most of it's $\ce{CO2}$.   There used to be a lot more of it in the atmosphere.